# Problema no Meteor com o comando para Android

Tags: android, apache-cordova, meteor

```
AVD - Sim
SDK - Sim
Adb - Sim

Meteor add-platform android - Sim
```

Todos funcionaram porem neste comando:

```
Meteor run android
```

acontece o seguinte erro:

> ```
> C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\Documents\Estudo - Projetos\simple-todo>meteor run android C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:190
>       throw error;
>       ^
> Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\Documents\Estudo - Projetos\simple-todo\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\version 'C:\Users\Raphael' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
>     at ChildProcess.exitCallback (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:151:23)
>     at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)  => awaited here:
>     at Function.Promise.await (C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:35:12)
>     at execFileSync (C:\tools\utils\processes.js:34:18)
>     at CordovaProject.installedVersionForPlatform (C:\tools\cordova\project.js:356:9)
>     at C:\tools\cordova\project.js:106:39
>     at C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:209:40
>     at _.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:87:22)
>     at Function._.some._.any (C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:208:5)
>     at C:\tools\cordova\project.js:100:26
>     at CordovaProject.createIfNeeded (C:\tools\cordova\project.js:97:41)
>     at new CordovaProject (C:\tools\cordova\project.js:89:10)
>     at C:\tools\cli\commands.js:349:30
>     at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:271:13
>     at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>     at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:264:29
>     at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>     at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:262:18
>     at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>     at C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:253:23
>     at [object Object].withValue (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
>     at Object.capture (C:\tools\utils\buildmessage.js:252:19)
>     at Object.main.captureAndExit (C:\tools\cli\main.js:271:29)
>     at Command.doRunCommand [as func] (C:\tools\cli\commands.js:348:10)
>     at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1483:23
>
> C:\Users\Raphael Kieling\Documents\Estudo - Projetos\simple-todo>
> ```

Alguem tem ideia de como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Esté aparentemente é um bug, e foi reportado recentemente no `meteor`:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7961

O problema é causado por espaços no caminho usado, a string depois de "Raphael" efetivamente está sendo entendida como parâmetro, e não como caminho do comando.

Em princípio uma solução imediata é mover a estrutura para um caminho sem espaços.

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda amigo!!!